# Angular form "required" validation making blank field truncated in result JSON

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have added angularjs form validation using "required" attribute in some form input element i.e. ng-modal and its working but field which are NOT marked required should come with null values.

Example :
In login form only "username" is required field and "password" and "remember-me" optional. It should generate JSON `{username : "admin" , password: null, rememberMe : false}` Now its generating `{username:"admin"}`

I need "allow-null" feature for some field in the form so that those field get populated in result JSON or scope object, which is used for rest call.

Please let me know how can i add "allow-null" like feature so that resultant JSON will be generated properly.

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing your template and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please see here:http://plnkr.co/edit/radR84QfaLPqs9GN98n2?p=preview
all you need is initialize your user object with empty string values or null values

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name:null,
    password:null,
    rememberMe :false


  };

  $scope.submit = function()
  {
    console.log($scope.user)
  }
});
```